# cannot find module grpc_node.node with Azure functions

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-cli

Trying simple azure function using CLI on Windows.  Other node projects work fine (so far).

Basic instructions from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/09/25/develop-azure-functions-on-any-platform/

```
npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@core
md JavaScriptHttp
Cd JavaScriptHttp
func init .
func new --language JavaScript --template HttpTrigger --name HttpTriggerJavaScript
func host start
```

Output noting problem fail below. note grpc_node.node error

> info: Worker.Node.531915e1-a572-4f3f-a900-9c2cafa7b427[0]
>         Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:5858/bb7ccba1-68a7-4547-b8e9-da0c9a87d59f info:
>   Worker.Node.531915e1-a572-4f3f-a900-9c2cafa7b427[0]
>         For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector info: Worker.Node.531915e1-a572-4f3f-a900-9c2cafa7b427[0] Couldn't require
>   bundle, falling back to Worker.js. Error: Cannot find module
>   'C:\Users\jhealy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v59-win32-x64\grpc_node.node'

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Node.js version 9.x? If so, you'll need to downgrade to 8.9 or lower version to make the function CLI work. See:

- [CLI doesn't work if node 9.x is installed #326](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/326)

Comment: wound up using the non core version .  issued the command "npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools" instead of "npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@core".  thanks for the dialog.